# React-native firebase Error: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to install https://rnfirebase.io/. when I init a new react-native file, it runs fine in ios.

The problem starts when I install RN Firebase, according to these docs:

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/ios

I get the following error (and when I try to run in xcode, I get the error in the screenshot below):

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test2.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test2.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

[image]

I've tried all the suggestions for similar problems and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all, after running pod install, use yourapp.xcworkspace, not yourapp.xcodeproject top open your project.

Once you open your project, add a Bundle identifier. Use that bundle identifier to create a firebase app as per the official tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

1.In docs it is recommended to put your Googleservice-info.plist file under ios/[YOUR APP NAME]/GoogleService-Info.plist. But it worked for me when i put it under ios/GoogleService-Info.plist.

2.Make sure that BUNDLE ID key in GoogleService-Info.plist file has your project's bundle id.